# Datepicker - Dates in milliseconds - Birthday Check

Tags: angular, date

I have a datepicker which return a chosen birthday date :

I convert is to Date in milliseconds :

```
   var datebirth = this.CreateUserForm.get('bdate').value;
    var tempdate = new Date(datebirth.year, datebirth.month-1, datebirth.day);
    user.bdate = tempdate.getTime();
```

Now I calculate age (that works)

```
var datetoday = new Date();
var ageDifMs = datetoday.getTime() - tempdate.getTime();
var age = Math.floor(ageDifMs / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365);
```

It returns the correct age.
Now I'm trying to check is today is the birthday !

```
var datetoday = new Date();
    console.log ('with HOURS '+datetoday.getTime());
    datetoday.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    console.log ('without HOURS '+datetoday.getTime());
    var ageDifMs = datetoday.getTime() - tempdate.getTime();
    var age = Math.floor(ageDifMs / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365);
    var agefull = ageDifMs / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365;
    if(age===agefull){
      bdaytoday= true;
    }
```

For year 2019 it works, but for earlier years (2010 in exemple)
 I obtain this results

age : 9
agefull : 9.005593607305936

If I use Math.Floor everyday will be a birthday.

Thanks to Joel Joseph :

```
datetoday.setFullYear(0);
    tempdate.setFullYear(0);

    if(datetoday.valueOf()===tempdate.valueOf()){
      bdaytoday= true;
    }
```

This way it works ! :D

Comment: please check this , may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407673/how-to-validate-age-and-alert-if-the-current-date-is-the-users-birthday

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing just the dates of today's date, and the birth date like this:

```
var tempDate = new Date('2019-10-29')

tempDate.getTime() === new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```